# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED https://<domain-name>/<context-root>/resources/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.js

Tags: css, http, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, connection

I have hosted our Spring webapp in AWS running on tomcat, In local the application is running fine and am able to use the application. But when i access the hosted application the page is loading but with out any of the resources like JS,CSS,Images etc.

and we get this error.
[image]

There is no difference between the localhost and the hosted URL.But we keeo getting this error and because of this the application is not working. And we are unsure whether its a configuration issue on the server side or anything.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means that your node server is not started. Double check that it's running on your server.

Comment: Hi, the server is up and running as its fetching the login.jsp file but not able to load the CSS, JS files that are referenced inside it. I even checked whether the path is right by hitting the URL of the CSS file directly from the browser i was able to see the .css file being retrieved in text format as expected. So i feel its a permission issue or some rights not properly given but am not familiar enough with AWS to understand more.